# Use of undefined constant issue

Tags: php, errors, constants

I have the following warning notice from my functions.php file:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant ENVIRONMENT - assumed 'ENVIRONMENT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

This is the code in my functions.php:

```
$dist_dir = get_theme_root_uri() . "/" . wp_get_theme() . "/dist";

/* environement */
// Set your environment/url pairs
$environments = array(
    'local' => 'local.mysite.com',
    'staging' => 'staging.mysite.com',
    'production' => 'mysite.com'
);

// Get the hostname
$http_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// Loop through $environments to see if there’s a match
foreach ($environments as $environment => $hostname) {
    //echo $hostname . " www";
    if (stripos($http_host, $hostname) !== false) {
        define('ENVIRONMENT', $environment);
        break;
    }
}

if (ENVIRONMENT == 'local') {
    define('ASSETSDIR', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets');
} else {
    define('ASSETSDIR', $dist_dir . '/assets');
}
```

The line in relation with the notice is this one:

```
if (ENVIRONMENT == 'local') {
```

I'm not sure to understand why there is this warning notice and how to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the hostnames in the `$environments` array are correct and free of typos? Also, you could change your `if()` to explicitly check that `ENVIRONMENT` is defined: `if ( defined( 'ENVIRONMENT' ) && 'local' === ENVIRONMENT ) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @PatJ. I modified the if() to check if the constant is defined as you mentioned and the warning disappeared.

Comment: @PatJ I let you post your comment above as the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your `$http_host` isn't in the list of possible choices. You can always check first that the `ENVIRONMENT` constant has actually been defined:

```
if ( defined( 'ENVIRONMENT' ) && 'local' === ENVIRONMENT ) { 
     define('ASSETSDIR', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets');
} else {
    define('ASSETSDIR', $dist_dir . '/assets');
}
```